# Filter analytics by QA and prod environments

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a site that has dev, qa, and prod environments. The same google analytics ID is in all three.

The sites have urls like this.

```
prod: https://example.org/term/project/
qa: https://example.org/term/projectQA/
devs: https://example.org/variousdevpaths
```

I've found several posts on the web [like this](http://gatipoftheday.com/apply-a-hostname-filter-for-development-and-staging-servers) about making filters, but I can't figure out how to properly filter what I've got.

I know it isn't working because at the moment only the prod site should be reporting and I'm getting big differences between all and my current prod filter.

I think it has to do with my lack of skills in regular expressions, maybe? Any advice on how to set these up?

Comment: Have you considered using different GA properties instead of filters?

Comment: I don't want to have to make changes to the code between the dev and prod environments. Also isn't that the point of filters? It seems like there should be a way to make them work, right?